# Unevenly distributed random number generation

Tags: algorithms, python, ruby, random

Let's say I have to generate random number from 1 to 100, however, the probability of each number is not 1/100, but a predefined probability.

How to generate that number? I use Ruby/Python.

Answer (score 4):

the algorithm itself is easy: create an array with all the weights' cumulative sum. After that you generate a `[0-1)` uniform random number and just binary search that number multiplied with the sum of the weights and the index will be the number you will need to generate.

Comment: +1 This is the easy way for small, discrete domains. Obviously it doesn't work for continuous (well, as continuous as you can get on a digital computer) and/or analytical distributions. Then you need an analytical solution like the [inversion method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).